# **How to list the contents of Multiple folder in Python Google Drive API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-drive-api

I am trying to programmatically list the contents of multiple folders. But somehow unable to put variable in

```
queryt = f'{parent_folder_id} in parents'
while True:
    response = service.files().list(q=f'{queryt}',
                                    spaces='drive',
                                    fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                    pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

The first variable **q** in **service.files().list** doesn't seem to accept variable but accepts direct values.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Parents is singular you can only list the constants of a single folder.

Comment: Okay. So if we pass values by one by one using for loop then also not possible?

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? In your situation, you want to retrieve the file list of all files in the specific folder including subfolders? Or you want to retrieve the file list in several individual folders?

Comment: Yes, I am assigning different folder to different writers, so that they can write their work there. My program will fetch the article inside them & check for readability, plag & other thing. Then it will write or append to a sheet in each writer folder with their article report. So I am not sure if I should go for parent folder or writer folder here but unable to do any currently. Thank you

Comment: @Pushkar Kathayat Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. From your replying, unfortunately, I couldn't understand whether you want to retrieve the file list of all files in the specific folder including subfolders or you want to retrieve the file list in several individual folders. And also, I couldn't understand about the result values you expect. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have figured it now. It was for an individual folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for the above issue can try.

```
        response = gdrive_service.files().list(
        q="parents in '"
          + folder_id + "' and trashed =""false",
        fields="nextPageToken, ""files(id, name)",
        pageSize=400).execute()
```

Thank you